Splitting some subsets of vertically split windows into even parts
Say I have a window layout like this
---------------------------------------------
|          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |
|    A     |    B     |    C     |    D     |
|          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |
---------------------------------------------

I want to leave A and B unchanged, but split C and D into 3 even parts like so
----------------------------------------------
|          |          |       |       |      |
|          |          |       |       |      |
|          |          |       |       |      |
|          |          |       |       |      |
|          |          |       |       |      |
|    A     |    B     |   E   |   F   |   G  |
|          |          |       |       |      |
|          |          |       |       |      |
|          |          |       |       |      |
|          |          |       |       |      |
|          |          |       |       |      |
|          |          |       |       |      |
----------------------------------------------

I know how to split one window with split-window-right or split-window-horizontally, but what if I want to take multiple windows and split them into even parts? What would be the best way to do this?
